# Как конвертировать JS объект в PHP объект?

Tags: ajax, json

Принятая PHP-скриптом JS-конструкция имеет такой вид: т.е. это строка, начиненная многомерным JS-массивом с ключами:

```
$obj={ "ar_10":[[ ["a","b"],["c","d"] ]  ,"ar_11":[ ["f","g"],["h","k"] ] ] };
```

Не получается добраться до начинки  `$obj` на PHP стороне. Помогите пожайлуста.

Comment: json_decode?...

Comment: Да.Оно. Это посылка JS массива. А как его разобрать на PHP -тормоза. Банально спрятать код хочу от копирования чтоб не светился в Хроме

Answer (score 0):

---

$myfile = fopen("newfile.txt" ,'w+') or die("Unable to open file!");

```
    как то смешно выходит:
 foreach($obj as  $key=>$val){
 foreach($val as  $ke){
 foreach($ke as  $ki){
 fwrite($myfile, $ki. ' ; ');
  };};};
```

---